# Is there a way to set Mediastore cursor to specific row in Rowset using where condition?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, kotlin, mediastore

I want to set the cursor to a specific row in a row set without to filter the row set. Is there a way to move cursor with where condition in row set? My solution in the moment is

```
// search for a _ID
if (cur != null) {       // my row set
        int idColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        do {
            if (search_id == cur.getInt(idColumn))) // row found
                return;                      // ok, cursor in right position
        } while (cur.moveToNext());
        cur.moveToFirst();                    // id not found
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not without looping through the Cursor, unless you know the position in advance in which case you could use `cur.moveToPosition(integer_posisition)`, where integer_position is as the name suggests, the position of the row in the Cursor, noting that the first row is row 0 and not 1.

Of course if you are searching for a particular row you would typically use the query to retrieve only that row using a WHERE clause.

Comment: Hmm, bad,  looping through the Cursor can be slow for huge row sets - thanks for answer!